# English statements into mathematical statements

Tags: real-analysis

So I have this statement:

Some integers less than 100 which are divisible by 7
can be written as 3 plus a multiple of 4"

I'm not sure the correct why to write it but I have many ways and they all kind of seem the same to me.

$∃x∈Z:x<100,\,7y=x \land3+4z=x:y,z∈Z$

or something like :

$∃x∈Z, x<100\,\land 3+4z=x\,\land 7y=x:y,z∈Z$

Sorry I'm quite new to this and I'm really confused about these notations and I also I was wondering when to use commas and when not to use commas. Our lecturer said in a pure mathematical proof commas aren't  used but in our text book commas are used to state the conditions on the set. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Exact syntax and notation can vary; you should ask your lecturer. Quite frankly, extra symbols should generally be avoided in favour of English words (obscuring a proof using symbols doesn't magically make it more rigorous). If we really have to use symbols though, here's my version:
$$
\exists x,y,z \in \mathbb Z ~~~\text{s.t.}~~~[(x < 100) \land (x = 7y = 3 + 4z)]
$$

Comment: I was wondering is the ":" synonymous with s.t.?

Comment: It depends, but I would think so. My "s.t." stands for "such that".

Answer (score 0):

If your lecturer does not like commas this would have to be
$$
(\exists x\in\mathbb Z)(\exists y\in\mathbb Z)(\exists z \in \mathbb Z) \quad [(x < 100) \wedge (x = 7y)\wedge (y = 3 + 4z)]
$$
and presumably he would be happy if you also simplified this to
$$
(\exists y\in\mathbb Z)(\exists z \in \mathbb Z) \quad [(7y < 100) \wedge (7y = 3 + 4z)]
$$

Comment: Would that not omit the x? How would the simplification work?

Comment: This involves a semantic simplification (the two proposations are sematically equivalent). It could be your instructor is only interested in syntactic formalisations at this point. You could ask her!